# Mongo conditional for "key doesn't exist"?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, key-value

I want to find a document using a conditional if the key == None or if the key doesn't exist. Something like this:

```
myDoc = self.request.root.db.myDocs.find_one({
                          '$or': [
                              {'myKey' : $doesNotExist } ,
                              {'myKey' : None }
                            ]
                    })
```

I'd also like to be able to find a document just by a missing key like this:

```
myDoc = self.request.root.db.myDocs.find_one( {'myKey' : $doesNotExist } )
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For "if key exists" checks, using a `.find()` is [significantly faster](http://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) than `find_one()`.

*Single document:* `cursor = db.myDocs.find({"mykey": {"$exists": True}}).limit(1)`

*Multiple documents:* `cursor = db.myDocs.find({"mykey": {"$exists": True}})`

```
if cursor.count() > 0:
    keyExists = True
else:
    keyExists = False
```

Answer (score 19):

You can test for a key not existing with:

```
db.myDocs.find_one({'myKey': { '$exists': False }})
```

Mongo documentation about the [$exists operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists)

Comment: I'm using MongoDB compass (1.24.6), and "False" didn't work but this worked: `{"myKey": {$exists: 0}}`